# python3.5 and cx_freeze exe error

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze

using python3.5 and cx-Freeze (4.3.4) and windows amd-64
i have tried to build the exe with this command:

```
python.exe setup.py build
```

Build produces no errors.

```
my setup.py 

import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(
    name = "Calendar and Weather",
    version = "1.0",
    description = "",
    executables = [Executable("cal.py")])
```

running exe produces errors:

```
AttributeError:module '_imp' has no attribue 'exec_builtin
```

here is my _bootstrap file

[_bootstrap](https://ideone.com/A4JcUn)

google search does not produce answers to this particular question.

**UPDATE**

```
I have run as suggested python setup.py bdist_msi. At the end of istall
there is a line 
copying build\exe.win-amd64-3.5\cal.exe -> build\bdist.win-amd64\msi
But the last line of install says that directory were cal.exe been copied
to is deleted.

removing 'build\bdist.win-amd64\msi' (and everything under it)

I have as a result of the build two directories in built.
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       10/12/2015   3:27 PM                bdist.win-amd64
d-----       10/12/2015   3:26 PM                exe.win-amd64-3.5

 bdist.win-amd64 is empty, and exe.win-amd64-3.5 has the exe, but it has
 timestamp of my last attempt 10 days ago to build it ? 
 And it gives the same error. I have deleted the build folder and run
 install again, but it did not help at all. Here what I have in 

    Directory: C:\Python35\Scripts\build\exe.win-amd64-3.5


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        10/2/2015   5:11 AM        1269248 cal.exe
-a----       10/12/2015   3:26 PM           5110 library.zip
-a----        9/13/2015   2:28 AM        3923736 python35.dll
-a----        9/13/2015   2:29 AM         868632 unicodedata.pyd
-a----        6/25/2015  11:15 PM          88752 VCRUNTIME140.dll
-a----        9/13/2015   2:28 AM          87320 _bz2.pyd

in library.zip there is importlib folder

C:\Python35\Scripts\build\exe.win-amd64-3.5\library.zip\importlib and 
it does contain __int__.pyc
```

PS C:\Python35\Scripts> python setup.py bdist_msi
running bdist_msi
running build
running build_exe
creating directory build\exe.win-amd64-3.5
copying C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\bases\Console.exe -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.5\cal.exe
copying C:\Python35\python35.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.5\python35.dll
copying C:\Python35\VCRUNTIME140.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.5\VCRUNTIME140.dll
*** WARNING *** unable to create version resource
install pywin32 extensions first
writing zip file build\exe.win-amd64-3.5\library.zip

Missing modules:
? _dummy_threading imported from dummy_threading
? _frozen_importlib_external imported from importlib, importlib._bootstrap
? calendar imported from _strptime, cal__main__
? ce imported from os
? datetime imported from _strptime, cal__main__
? doctest imported from heapq
? getopt imported from base64, quopri
? json imported from cal__main__
? org.python.core imported from copy
? os.path imported from os
? posix imported from os
? pwd imported from posixpath
? requests imported from cal__main__
? subprocess imported from os
This is not necessarily a problem - the modules may not be needed on this platform.

copying C:\Python35\DLLs_bz2.pyd -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.5_bz2.pyd
copying C:\Python35\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.5\unicodedata.pyd
installing to build\bdist.win-amd64\msi
running install_exe
creating build\bdist.win-amd64
creating build\bdist.win-amd64\msi
copying build\exe.win-amd64-3.5\cal.exe -> build\bdist.win-amd64\msi
copying build\exe.win-amd64-3.5\library.zip -> build\bdist.win-amd64\msi
copying build\exe.win-amd64-3.5\python35.dll -> build\bdist.win-amd64\msi
copying build\exe.win-amd64-3.5\unicodedata.pyd -> build\bdist.win-amd64\msi
copying build\exe.win-amd64-3.5\VCRUNTIME140.dll -> build\bdist.win-amd64\msi
copying build\exe.win-amd64-3.5_bz2.pyd -> build\bdist.win-amd64\msi
removing 'build\bdist.win-amd64\msi' (and everything under it)

**update**

```
I have started using pyinstaller instead. And it works fine for my. I have run 
pyistaller with .\pyinstaller.exe --onefile .\cal.py and got what I wanted.
```